What is the relationship between a degenerate limiting distribution and its scaled non-degenerate distribution?
In my statistics class, we are covering modes of convergence: a.s., $L_p$, probability, weak convergence of measure. To motivate the limiting theorems that we will be covering next, my professor presented the following example:
Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ be a sequence of random variables distributed i.i.d. according to $\text{Unif}(0,1)$. Define $Y_n = X_{(n)}$ where $X_{(n)} = \max(X_1, \ldots,X_n)$. It follows that $Y_n$ converges in probability to $Y$ where $\mathbb{P}(Y = 1) = 1$.
However, this is a degenerate distribution and my professor argues that it does not tell us how a sample will deviate from the limiting value. Thus, we need to find a non-degenerate distribution through a rescaling. Specifically, let $\tilde{Y}_n = n(1- X_{(n)})$. Then, through some algebra $\tilde{Y_n}$ converges in distribution to an exponential distribution.
I am confused by what this rescaled random variable actually represents. What is source of randomness is across this exponential distribution? What is the relationship between $Y_n$ and $\tilde{Y}_n$? Moreover, since the limiting distribution does not depend on $n$, what are the type of probabilistic statements we can make with this limiting distribution?
More generally, I've always been intuitively taught that  the central limit theorem tells us the behavior of the sample mean of $n$ samples as the number of batched $n$ samples we draw go to infinity. However, it is unclear to me how this is conveyed through the formal measure-theoretic statement of the central limit theorem, where $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n - \mu) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$.
I've consulted classic textbooks such as Statistical Inference by Casella and Berger, Asymptotic Statistics by van der Vaart, and Theory of Probability and Random Processes by Koralov and Sinai, but none detail the nature of this transformation or its motivation other than it can be used to prove CLT.

First, it's important not to conflate distribution with randomness. A distribution is essentially an idealized version of a histogram, representing the frequency of occurrence for each data value (or what we believe it would be) in a dataset. In other words, a distribution is simply a summary of given data or an idealized version of such.
Of course, a distribution may summarize what would be (or have been) observed in repeated random experiments. For example, in OP's case, each trial of the random experiment consists of generating a sample of uniformly chosen numbers $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ and then observing the value of $\tilde{Y}_n = n(1 - X_{(n)})$. The statement
$$ \text{Law of $\tilde{Y}_n$}
\quad \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} \quad
\text{Exp}(1) $$
then means that, for large $n$ and many repetitions of this experiment, the distribution of observed values of $\tilde{Y}_n$ would closely approximate the exponential distribution with unit rate:

However, this does not imply that each $\tilde{Y}_n$ converges in probability to anything. Indeed, below is an instance of the trajectory of $n \mapsto \tilde{Y}_n$ for a sufficiently long sample $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ in a single simulation run:

